# How to patch Log4j2 0-day exploit

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

We are using Java for one of our services which uses log4j2 library. As of December 10, 2021, an exploit was found to execute remote code for Java using log4j2. I am wondering what is the best way to address this? Is it suitable to just use another Java logging library instead? Or is there a configuration for log4j2 so that we won’t have to go through all that trouble changing the logging library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We should upgrade log4j to version `2.17.0` (available at [`mvnrepository.com`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core/2.15.0)). [As per the security notes (`logging.apache.org`)](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/security.html), the vulnerability is fixed in `2.15.0`. There are, however, two other vulnerabilities in `2.15.0`, which were patched in `2.16.0` and `2.17.0` respectively.

The security notes also list actions to mitigate the exploit if upgrading is (currently) not an option:

> Mitigation: In releases >=2.10, this behavior can be mitigated by setting either the system property `log4j2.formatMsgNoLookups` or the environment variable `LOG4J_FORMAT_MSG_NO_LOOKUPS` to `true`. For releases from 2.0-beta9 to 2.10.0, the mitigation is to remove the `JndiLookup` class from the classpath: `zip -q -d log4j-core-*.jar org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/JndiLookup.class`.

If we are using `spring-boot-starter-logging` with no additional configuration, we are not affected. For details, see the [spring-boot infromation on the issue (`spring.io`)](https://spring.io/blog/2021/12/10/log4j2-vulnerability-and-spring-boot).

Similarly, we are not affected when we are using quarkus, as long as we do not add the `log4j` dependency explicitly. See [the corresponding github issue (`github.com`)](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/discussions/22108)